# Slider value doesn't update even if state is changing

Tags: flutter, slider

I'm getting mad to understand why the slider inside a statefulBuilder won't update its value even if the state is continually changed by an audioPlayer listener function. Other values inside the same builder updates (the button icons for instance), but the slider keeps staying in its initial position even if it remains draggable.

I've searched the web and this site for two full days. I'm adding the link to the file on git to avoid pasting the entire file here

https://github.com/Adriano72/wccm/blob/master/lib/pages/john_main_talks.dart

Comment: Please paste a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example so people can help you with your specific problem.

Comment: Just a quick glance, did you check `position?.inMilliseconds?.toDouble()` is a valid number or not null in each update (`setState`) ?

Comment: Thanks, Tim and Tokenyet for your quick reply! I found out the problem, eventually, I fixed that. The problem was that I was not using properly the statefulBuilder. In fact, it was not rebuilding its widget tree cause I misplaced some variables in the code. Anyway, I have turned in the right direction thanks to your suggestion!